Intermediate points in a line chart in Apache echartJS?
I am trying to find intermediate points between two points connected by a line in a line chart using Apache EChartsJS.
`https://jsfiddle.net/fnxzb2cq/2/

Here when you hover over the point, the value shows up as an alert. But I am looking for values for intermediate points which are interpolated .e.g, in the graph above, when I hover over the line corresponding to the point 15 in the x-axis, it should alter value of ~ 175.
Is this possible through echart's API or do we need to create a custom fit line and then do the calculations in a different function and just display the results of the function while it hovers?
Thanks.

I've imported your code here.
Then I interpolated the series from n items to 2*n-1 items, using the following function:
function interpolate(arr) {
  var result = []
  if (arr.length) {
    result.push(arr[0])
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      result.push((arr[i - 1] + arr[i]) * 0.5)
      result.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return result;
}



var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("lineChart"))
var categories = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
var data = [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260]

function interpolate(arr) {
  var result = []
  if (arr.length) {
    result.push(arr[0])
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      result.push((arr[i - 1] + arr[i]) * 0.5)
      result.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return result;
}


// specify chart configuration item and data
var option = (option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: "category",
    data: interpolate(categories),
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: "value",
    triggerLineEvent: true,
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'line1',
    triggerLineEvent: true,
    data: interpolate(data),
    type: "line",
  }, ],
})

// use configuration item and data specified to show chart
myChart.setOption(option);
#lineChart {
  background: gray;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="lineChart" style="height: 290px;"></div>



Update
We shall use the <canvas> element click event to find the relative coordinates of the mouse. Then we will find distance from all data points in order to find the nearest two. Then we can interpolate and get the value of the data (y), at that x position.


var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("lineChart"))

document.getElementById("lineChart").addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
  var mouseX = ev.offsetX
  var mouseY = ev.offsetY

  var series = myChart.getModel().getSeries()[0] // Get the first series
  var data = series.getData()
  var coordSys = series.coordinateSystem

  var distances = []

  for (var i = 0; i < data.count(); i++) {
    var value = data.getValues(i)
    var point = coordSys.dataToPoint(value)

    var distance = Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(mouseX - point[0], 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - point[1], 2),
    )

    distances.push({
      index: i,
      distance: distance,
      dataValue: value,
      pixelCoord: point,
    })
  }

  // Sort distances and get the two nearest points
  distances.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)
  var nearestTwo = distances.slice(0, 2)
  nearestTwo.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index)

  let x1 = nearestTwo[0].pixelCoord[0]
  let y1 = nearestTwo[0].pixelCoord[1]
  let x2 = nearestTwo[1].pixelCoord[0]
  let y2 = nearestTwo[1].pixelCoord[1]
  let xMouse = mouseX
  let yMouse = mouseY

  // Calculate the distance from the mouse to the line
  let numerator = Math.abs(
    (y2 - y1) * xMouse - (x2 - x1) * yMouse + x2 * y1 - y2 * x1,
  )
  let denominator = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) + Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2))
  let distanceToLine = numerator / denominator

  if (distanceToLine < 3) {
    // Linear interpolation for Y at the mouse's X position
    y1 = nearestTwo[0].dataValue[1]
    y2 = nearestTwo[1].dataValue[1]
    let interpolatedY = y1 + ((xMouse - x1) / (x2 - x1)) * (y2 - y1)
    console.log("Interpolated Y value:", interpolatedY.toFixed(2))
  }
})

// specify chart configuration item and data
var option = (option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: "category",
    data: ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70"],
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: "value",
    triggerLineEvent: true,
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "line1",
      triggerLineEvent: true,
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: "line",
    },
  ],
})

// use configuration item and data specified to show chart
myChart.setOption(option)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="lineChart" style="height: 390px; border: 1px solid gray"></div>




The idea is not to add any points on the graph and possibly use echart's API to get any intermediate values. There can be any number of intermediate values in within those points. I expected there to be a way to get those rendered values that were dynamically generated while creating the line. The interpolated values that were generated using an interpolation algorithm might not be the same that were generated by echart's line drawing algorithm... Just trying to understand the best generic way to achieve this. Any ideas ?

do you want to get the value of the graph where you click (hover) it, even in between points?

Yes, even in between points, as the library already draws it on the graph.

You could skip the calculation to determine if the line was clicked by using the echarts click event

That event only is fired when clicking on the data points.

Yes that is what I was trying to do, if it was possible to find where in the graph a click was done and whether the click overlapped on the line or not, that way the calculation could have been skipped, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution. even though the calculation way works, but was expecting more flexible API from the library.

The actual drawing of the pixels is relegated to the lower level libraries, either canvas or svg, echarts doesn't "know" the pixels that are set. Also, those libraries don't offer "inverse" methods, to access pixels, at least not those corresponding to one drawing operation like a line or a curve. That's why a computed interpolation as in this @ITgoldman 's  solution is the best one can reasonably expect.

@ITgoldman If you set triggerLineEvent = true (as you did in your example) the click event is also fired on line clicks, see here

its logging the event to the console

You are right. They added this version 5, whereas OP was using version 4.
